# Seleccionar registros segun ID con EntityFrameWork

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web, entity-framework

Nuevo trabajo y la prueba es la siguiente

Tengo esta funcion que recibe un parametro de tipo (DbGeography) la cual selecciona un conjunto de resultados y me devuelve una lista , ahora lo que nesecito es cambiar el parametro por (int RestaurantID) y hacer la misma seleccion pero segun este campo ( ya Se ..que puede ser no nesesario devolver una lista ya que solo se va a seleccionar un registro...pero es q por ahora debe hacerse asi ..luego debo cambiarlo)

```
public List<VistaRestaurantSearch> SearchRestaurant(DbGeography geografi)
        {
            List<VistaRestaurantSearch> vista = new List<VistaRestaurantSearch>();
            var rest = (from de in se.DeliveryConfiguration join re in se.restaurant on de.Restaurantid equals re.RestaurantID
                        where (de.Position.Distance(geografi)/1000) < de.Distance select re).ToList();

            foreach (var item in rest)
            {
                vista.Add(new VistaRestaurantSearch() {
                    restaurant = item,
                    config = se.DeliveryConfiguration.Where(a => a.Restaurantid == item.RestaurantID).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Horary = new EngineRestaurant().getRestaurantHourbyRestaurant(item.RestaurantID),
                    prom = new EngineReview().getReviewAverage(item.RestaurantID)
                });

            }

            return vista;

        }
```

y estas mis tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias implementar algo como ser

```
public List<VistaRestaurantSearch> SearchRestaurant(int RestaurantID)
{

    var query = (from de in se.DeliveryConfiguration 
                join re in se.restaurant on de.Restaurantid equals re.RestaurantID
                where re.RestaurantID == RestaurantID
                select new{
                    Delivery = se,
                    Restaurant = re
                }).ToList();

    var rest = query.Select(x=> new VistaRestaurantSearch()
                        {
                            restaurant = x.Restaurant,
                            config = se.DeliveryConfiguration.Where(a => a.Restaurantid == x.Restaurant.RestaurantID).FirstOrDefault(),
                            Horary = new EngineRestaurant().getRestaurantHourbyRestaurant(x.Restaurant.RestaurantID),
                            prom = new EngineReview().getReviewAverage(x.Restaurant.RestaurantID)
                        }).ToList();

    return rest;

}
```

no necesitas realizar un `foreach` de la respuesta del linq para transformar en otra entidad, lo realizas directo en el `select`

Ademas para completar las propiedades de `Horary` y `prom` no puedes realizar un join con las otras tablas para resolverlo, asi no tienes que ir a las otras clases y se resuelve en una unica query

Comment: Me devuelve este ERROR : EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario

Información adicional: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SaborWebApp.RestaurantHours] getRestaurantHourbyRestaurant(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: claro esto sucede por lo que comentaba, cuando EF convierte el linq en una query sql no puede recolver los metodos getRestaurantHourbyRestaurant() y getReviewAverage() es por eso que en el ultimo parrafo comente si podrias evitar estos y esa infor unirla como join del linq

Comment: Por eso te pregunto Leandro se puede hacer con el ForEach asi resuelvo ..porque ya existen metodos  que estan esperando ese resultado y lo nesesito con caracter urgente

Comment: edite la respuesta, en este caso se aplican dos partes una que unen la entidad y ejecuta la query contra la db y otra que realzia la transformacion sobre los datos en memoria. Lo que no estoy muy seguro es cuando defne el "config" ya que usas nuevamente el "se" que no se de donde sale